# Error after upgrading to Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache

The "a2ensite""a2dissite" are not working

Echo:

> ERROR: Site XXXXXX does not exist!

I swear it exists in sites-available folder.

After I typed `a2ensite` and double clicked the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button, it shows the `/root` directory.

There must be something wrong with the a2en/dissite script.

How can I make it back to work?

=====================
Here are the last lines of the error log:

```
[Sun Aug 04 22:59:31.406192 2013] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5378:tid 140459282536256] AH00489: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 04 22:59:31.406433 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5378:tid 140459282536256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Aug 04 23:09:44.648984 2013] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5378:tid 140459282536256] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 04 23:09:46.001182 2013] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 5692:tid 139671144335168] AH00489: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 04 23:09:46.001490 2013] [core:notice] [pid 5692:tid 139671144335168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Renaming site configuration files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*` into `*.conf` helped.

Example, when enabling site `dummy.com`, configuration file must be named `dummy.com.conf`.

Comment: so great, thanks a lot! That helped me figuring out why 2.4.6 wouldn't work properly at all for me (it was only partways loading my config somehow...not enabling SSL but still loading the aliases and directories in the already "enabled" site (i.e. there was a link to a page which was not in a .conf file)... so the files were accessible but only over ssl, on the ssl port... and that without any hint in the logs or on the command line! Very weird and user-unfriendly, that...

Answer (score 14):

Another solution is to change this line in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` from:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

to:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*
```

Comment: Only thing to keep in mind with this method is that the main apache2.conf file is part of the apache2 package, so the change could get reverted by upgrades. It is usually better to make changes outside of apache2.conf where possible.